# A proxy problem of "sudo apt-get install"

Tags: installation, apt, proxy

I am trying to install a package `python-pygments` under Ubuntu. After launching `sudo apt-get install python-pygments`, it is blocked:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Suggested packages:
  ttf-bitstream-vera
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  python-pygments
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 43 not upgraded.
Need to get 347 kB of archives.
After this operation, 2,527 kB of additional disk space will be used.
0% [Connecting to cache.polytechnique.fr (129.104.38.6)]
```

`cache.polytechnique.fr` in the line line is the proxy of my school. A download in the campus should work, but the problem is that I am physically not in the campus. I try to remove proxy setting via Chromium (the method of network proxy: NONE), it still drives to `cache.polytechnique.fr`, does anyone know how to let `sudo` avoid this proxy?

Comment: my question is you got internet explorer in ubuntu? ... changing the proxy of browser don't change the proxy for apt...and you might have used global proxy settings ..so disable that.

Comment: It is actually Chromium, I have amended it... could you please tell me how to disable the global proxy settings?

Comment: what is you ubuntu version ..it is 11.10?

Answer (score 3):

You probably set the proxy settings globally, so that they applied to all applications, including `apt-get`.

When you turn off the proxy settings, click the button that says "Apply system wide" (or something like that). It will prompt you for your password. Now you need to restart Terminal in order to have the settings applied.

---

If that does not solve the issue, see if `/etc/apt/apt.conf` exists. This can be done with:

```
cat /etc/apt/apt.conf
```

If the file exists (if you see some output), open it up. This can be done with:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/apt/apt.conf
```

If the file contains a line with `Acquire::http::Proxy` in it, delete the line, or put a `#` in front of the line. Save the file and exit the text editor.

Try `sudo apt-get` command again.

Answer (score 0):

You can add following line in `/etc/apt/apt.conf`:

```
Acquire::http::proxy DIRECT;
```